# External Javascript not working, it is greyed out by Atom. They are in the same folder, is it just Atom or am I just stupid?

Tags: javascript

[External Js not working, greyed out by Atom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90WVM.png)
Not-working: The button is not showing on the site and the script is greyed out so it is not active as if it was a comment.

The html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>JavaScriptGyak3</title>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="page3.js" </script>

</head>
<body id="test">
  <button type="button" onclick="hatszin()"> Change Background </button>
</body>
</html>
```

The js code is just:

```
function hatszin() {
  document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundColor = 'orange';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, had to give the body context (I placed a h1 in there) and now everything looks like shows like as it should.

Comment: ah ok, I just put a comment in the other answer, I did not notice you had the onclick there.... sorry my bad! :P

Answer (score 3):

You need to close the opening `<script>` tag properly by adding a `>`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="page3.js"> </script>
                                             ^
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="page3.js"></script> did that still not working :(
copy-pasted what you wrote, but it's still grey.

Not-working: The button is not showing on the site and the script is greyed out so it is not active as if it was a comment.

Comment: @TheHungryOne define "not working"

Comment: in the js file you are just defining the hatszin function? if so, it's natural that nothing happens

Comment: @DarioPiotrowicz Yes only that, I started exactly half an hour ago learning, not sure why that is a problem.

Comment: it's not a problem you are defining a function, that means that you are creating that function and you can use it to do what you specified in it, which in this case is changing the background color of the test div. But if you don't call that function then it simply does nothing, you just created it but aren't using it.

Comment: just add this to your `body` : onload="hatszin()" , this basically calls the function you just created when the page loads :)

Comment: @DarioPiotrowicz I see, thank you, will look out for that in the future.

Comment: No sorry ignore that, I just didn't notice you were already using the function in the onclick :)